# Updating a page using a button value added to the same page using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new at ajax stuff.
I have a `add_tournament` page which takes in a tournament name and later using ajax shows that added tournament name on that same page. I am doing something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("#add-tournament").click(function() {
         var name = $("#name").val();
         $.ajax({
             url: '/home/',
             method: 'POST',
             data: JSON.stringify({name: name}),
             success: function() {
                 /*console.log(arguments)*/

             },
             error: function() {
                 console.log(arguments)
             }
         })
     })
</script>
```

What to put into success function?

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you are trying to do but first argument of success callabck is what is returned from server: `success: function(data) { console.log("server returns:', data); }`. So what are you looking for?

Comment: You also don't need to convert your object to a string Jquery will except a plain object and convert it to post vars.

Comment: @A.Wolff What I am trying to ask for instance after having this comment written I hit Add Comment and the comment was added without refreshing!